# SAML authentication with firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, saml

Is there a way to authenticate a user with SAML token using firebase as a backend? The company I am working with requires that SAML is used within the authentication system and I am not sure if this is possible with firebase as a backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Maybe new GCP service ["Cloud Identity for Customers and Partners"](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/) (in beta for now) could help you.

> Cloud Identity for Customers and Partners (CICP) provides an identity platform that allows users to authenticate to your applications and services, like multi-tenant SaaS applications, mobile/web apps, games, APIs and more. CICP is built on an enhanced Firebase Authentication infrastructure, so it's perfect if you're building a service on Firebase, Google Cloud Platform (GCP), or on another platform, and need secure, easy-to-use authentication.

You can check [SAML provider](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-saml), Firebase is behind the scene.

> This guide shows how to enable an existing web application for Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0, with Cloud Identity for Customers and Partners (CICP). This will include accepting SAML assertions from identity providers (IdP) as a SAML service provider, verifying their contents, and producing a lightweight JWT that you can use in your application to verify authentication and perform authorization.

Hope it will help.

**Updated on February 25th, 2020 :**

[I published a tutorial](https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6) on how to integrate SAML authentication with Firebase and Angular app.

Comment: @Thierry Falvo I followed your tutorial to a T and I'm getting `{code: "auth/invalid-credential", message: "The SAMLResponse does not match Rp Entity Id in storage", a: null`. google searching the error message is not helping me much

Comment: @Thierry I just posted a question to your very nicely done article.

Comment: WARNING TO REACT NATIVE USERS: 

    "Headful" auth methods such as signInWithPopup(), signInWithRedirect(), linkWithPopup(), and linkWithRedirect() do not work in React Native (or Cordova, for that matter). You can still sign in or link with a federated provider by using signInWithCredential() with an OAuth token from your provider of choice."
-https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/firebase-react-native.html

Answer (score 6):

You can now use SAML provider with the new [Cloud Identity platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/). This platform works in combination with Firebase too.

Check [Thierry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322424/209103) for more details.

---

**Old/outdated answer** below:

At the moment there is no built-in SAML provider for Firebase Authentication. See this [discussion on the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/tUYXF7GRTqQ). From that post:

> To support SAML authentication with Firebase Auth, you need to [use custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).
>
> When the SAML response is posted to your server, your convert the SAML assertion to a custom token (minted via Firebase Admin SDK) and then pass that token to the client where you signInWithCustomToken. You can add any additional SAML claims to the custom token claims and they will propagate to the Firebase ID token JWT.

It's a valid feature request though, so I highly recommend to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Hi @frank-van-puffelen. Thanks for the info. I filed a feature request. Is this on your roadmap? I see both AWS Cognito and Azure Active Directory B2C support both SAML and AD federation. It's a sorely missing feature in Firebase.

Comment: Has there been any update on this? Does/will firebase support SAML2.0? Or Frank, do you know of anyone who has actively implemented custom Authentication in Firebase to support SAML ?

Comment: See Thierry's answer for an update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322424