# Implementing Cross Project User Auth (Single Sign On) like Google account using Firebase / GCP

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on

I was searching for a simple way to link 2 or more project users just like google account for Youtube, Google Drive and Amazon account for amazon app & prime video app

On mobile these apps don't really require you to enter your credentials again but use the same account, without need of creating a new one as an account is already created by the user for another service from the same Provider/Company.

Is there any way to use Firebase / GCP to implement such functionality??

I also saw this thread, but it is using a third party identity provider called jumpCloud, is there any way I can build it from scratch?
https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you would need to use The identity platform in tandem with [Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml).

Please also check the detailed answers provided on the [Stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284067/saml-authentication-with-firebase/52287289#52287289) which is related to Implementing Cross Project User Auth (Single Sign On) like Google account using Firebase/ GCP.

It seems like there is already a [Feature Request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2291) opened to have this feature implemented if the above two solutions are not  applicable to your situation.

Comment: As identity platform uses firebase client sdk's, all things suggest me is to use the same project for both the services ?

Comment: are you asking this as a question? As there is a FR for this, you can expect it to happen in the future. In the meantime, there are solutions for this as stated by Sohail.